# RavenDB C# client throws error as Invalid node tag character: n

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to remove a document in RavenDB which has 3 nodes running in a single machine (development setup).
Below is the code for removing the document.

```
public bool Remove<T>(string id) where T : new()
{
    bool bResult = false;
    using (var session = _session.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Delete(id);
        session.SaveChanges();
        bResult = true;
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

but it throws error on the line `session.SaveChanges();`

> Invalid node tag character: n ...

Stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid node tag character: n
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Replication.ChangeVectorParser.ThrowInvalidNodeTag(Char ch) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Replication\ChangeVectorParser.cs:line 71
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Replication.ChangeVectorParser.ParseNodeTag(String changeVector, Int32 start, Int32 end) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Replication\ChangeVectorParser.cs:line 52
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Replication.ChangeVectorParser.MergeChangeVector(String changeVector, List`1 entries) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Replication\ChangeVectorParser.cs:line 186
   at Raven.Server.Utils.ChangeVectorUtils.MergeVectors(String vectorAstring, String vectorBstring) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Utils\ChangeVectorUtils.cs:line 213
   at Raven.Server.Documents.DocumentsStorage.CreateTombstone(DocumentsOperationContext context, Slice lowerId, Int64 documentEtag, CollectionName collectionName, String docChangeVector, Int64 lastModifiedTicks, String changeVector, DocumentFlags flags, NonPersistentDocumentFlags nonPersistentFlags) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\DocumentsStorage.cs:line 1378
   at Raven.Server.Documents.DocumentsStorage.Delete(DocumentsOperationContext context, Slice lowerId, String id, LazyStringValue expectedChangeVector, Nullable`1 lastModifiedTicks, String changeVector, CollectionName collectionName, NonPersistentDocumentFlags nonPersistentFlags, DocumentFlags documentFlags) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\DocumentsStorage.cs:line 1195
   at Raven.Server.Documents.DocumentsStorage.Delete(DocumentsOperationContext context, String id, String expectedChangeVector) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\DocumentsStorage.cs:line 1091
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Handlers.BatchHandler.MergedBatchCommand.ExecuteCmd(DocumentsOperationContext context) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Handlers\BatchHandler.cs:line 706
   at Raven.Server.Documents.TransactionOperationsMerger.ExecutePendingOperationsInTransaction(List`1 pendingOps, DocumentsOperationContext context, Task previousOperation, DurationMeasurement& meter) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\TransactionOperationsMerger.cs:line 825
   at Raven.Server.Documents.TransactionOperationsMerger.MergeTransactionsOnce() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\TransactionOperationsMerger.cs:line 500
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Raven.Server.Documents.TransactionOperationsMerger.Enqueue(MergedTransactionCommand cmd) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\TransactionOperationsMerger.cs:line 124
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Handlers.BatchHandler.BulkDocs() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Handlers\BatchHandler.cs:line 96
   at Raven.Server.Routing.RequestRouter.HandlePath(RequestHandlerContext reqCtx) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\Routing\RequestRouter.cs:line 124
   at Raven.Server.RavenServerStartup.RequestHandler(HttpContext context) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\src\Raven.Server\RavenServerStartup.cs:line 172
```

Comment: Can you update your first code sample? This is not valid C#: "bResult = **Background:**true;"

Comment: Can you show the output of the request as it is captured by Fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same error yesterday. I restored database on the different machine where I installed brand new RavenDB and (being lazy) named new instance node "A". It appears that RavenDB cannot currently remove documents when change vector and instance tag name don't match.

[node-tag-mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOjvp.png)

It looks like an honest mistake in code instead of intentional behavior.. but its only my guess, because I didn't find anything about this behavior in 4.1 documentation.

**Solution** (if you confirm there is a mismatch):

You could try to add a new node to your cluster with the name matching change vector of locked documents.

<strike>In my case I am not able to configure standalone RavenDB to have node tag of more than 4 characters (that was no problem on Docker)... It might be harder to get database to consistent state then.</strike>

Alternatively try exporting and importing data. It fixes the problem because change vectors are updated and match new node tag.